# Как браузер записывает данные в буфер (нюанс)

Tags: браузер

Как только я не гуглил, но ничего похожего на нужный мне ответ не нашел.

В общем, по сабжу.

Так вот, как это происходит в механизме браузера? Как он записывает скопированные данные в буфер?

Что натолкнуло меня на создания данной темы, так это то, что в поле с атрибутом contenteditable браузер вставляет копируемый текст (если он был скопирован в браузере) со всеми тегами, а, к примеру, в нотепад вставляется голый текст без всяких тегов.

По началу я думал, что у браузера еще есть какой-то отдельный "буфер", но после того как я копировал текст в мозиле и вставил его в хром, то теги тоже вставились, следовательно: тут что-то тайное сокрыто)

Почему это происходит? Почему в любое текстовое поле, отличное от браузеров (contenteditable), текст вставляется без тегов?

Извините, если не совсем корректно описал вопрос!

Comment: Скопируйте в Word и удивитесь ;)

Comment: Никогда не работал в ворде, но думаю, если бы в процессе создания этого поста я о нём вспомнил, то не исключил того варианта, что в него тоже с тегами добавляется текст)

Comment: Выходит, что программы (редакторы) просто напросто игнорируют эти теги? Или в буфер добавляется текст двух вариантов, а именно с тегами и без?

Comment: Чуть про буфер обмена https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Вот я клоун. Столько всякой инфы про кольцевые буферы и прочее читал. Теперь понятно. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите.

Когда вы копируете данные в буфер обмена, вы на самом деле копируете не одну порцию данных. Программа, которая помещает данные в буфер, может поместить их в [различных форматах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013.aspx).

Например, это могут быть текст в OEM-кодировке, текст в Unicode-кодировке, RTF для сохранения форматирования, и HTML для браузеров. Программа, которая вставляет из буфера, перебирает список форматов, находит наиболее подходящий для себя, и вставляет текст именно в этом формате.

Таким образом, Notepad, который умеет обрабатывать только текст, вставляет данные в этом формате. Браузер, когда вставляет в текстовое поле, тоже выбирает текстовый формат. А вот браузер, вставляющий в contenteditable, вполне может воспользоваться форматом HTML, если такой есть в буфере. Точно так же и другие программы, поддерживающие форматированный текст (например, MS Word или OpenOffice), могут вставить текст в формате с форматированием (HTML или RTF).

Кстати, то, что данные доступны в нескольких форматах — добрая воля программы, которая *положила* туда данные в этих форматах. Никакой автоматической конверсии сам буфер обмена не производит.